# Suggest a chart type for this problem in core plot

Tags: ios, core-plot

There are Two indicators let it be Product A and Product B whose cost are compared over years.
Cost is along Y-axis and Year is along X-axis.

I want two lines(Horizontal lines) indicating the two products (A and B) should stretch over this graph implying as Cost of Product A  for 1st year is $xx,2nd year $xx, same for 3rd year as well.Similarly Cost of Product B for 1st year is $yy,2nd year $yy, same for 3rd year as well.

If it gets picturized it will be like two lines(blue for product A and Pink color for product B)horizontally runs in the graph at $xx position and $yy position along Y-axis and the bottom part of the line in the graph should fill the colors accordingly.

To give a clear picture

```
     | 
  $yy|--------------------(product B line in pink color)
     |all pink color
  $xx|--------------------(product A line in blue color)
     |all (pink+blue) color
     |
     |
  $0 |______________________

      1st yr   2nd yr  3rd yr(x-axis)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two scatter plots--one for product A and one for product B. Give each plot an area fill and make sure the fill color used for the front plot (product A in your sample above) has an alpha value that allows the pink fill from product B to show through.

Comment: @Eric-Thanks.It works fine but the color fill is not going down when the slider value is less than earlier value.Because of this slider color is bit higher to slider in the graph if the slider value goes down.I have given bandFill only in the slider changing action.What might have gone wrong?

Comment: Use the areaFill property. It will fill the area between the scatter plot line and areaBaseValue and will be redrawn whenever the plot data changes.